# How to repeat a loop after the loop has been finished

Tags: java, while-loop, count, java.util.scanner, generator

I am doing an assignment that asks to create a guessing game but I have already coded the guessing game. I need to ask the user if they want to play the guessing game again in which I need to re-trigger the loop. I am not sure how to re-trigger after the first loop as already been executed and finished.

Here is my code for the Guessing game:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ThreeEleven
{


 public static void main (String[] args)
    {
final int MAX = 100;
int answer, guess;
String again;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print ("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and "
+ MAX + ". Guess what it is: (or enter 0 to quit) ");
guess = scan.nextInt();

Random generator = new Random(); //Random generator. 1 to 100.
answer = generator.nextInt(MAX) +1;

    //if (guess == answer){ //If guess equals answer
        //System.out.println ("You got it! Good guessing!");

    //}
    //else if (guess == 0){ //Game ends
        //System.out.println ("You have ended your game. Goodbye.");

    //}

        while (guess != answer && guess != 0){ //If guess and 0 is not answer, continue.

            if (guess > answer && guess != 0){ //If guess is higher than answer
                System.out.println ("You guessed too high!");
                guess = scan.nextInt();

            }
            else{
                if (guess < answer && guess != 0){ //If guess is lower than answer
                    System.out.println ("You guessed too low!");
                    guess = scan.nextInt();
                }

                else if (guess == answer){ //If guess equals answer
                    System.out.println ("You got it! Good guessing!");
                }
                else if (guess == 0){ //Game ends
                    System.out.println ("You have ended your game. Goodbye.");
                }
                    }
}
        if (guess == answer){
            System.out.println ("You got it! Good guessing!");
           //System.out.println ("You guessed " +  + " times");

 //  System.out.println ("Want to play again? (yes or no)?");
       // again = scan.next();
      //  if (again == "yes")
     //   {
           // System.out.print ("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and "


// + MAX + ". Guess what it is: (or enter 0 to quit) ");
    //guess = scan.nextInt();
           // while (again == "yes")
           // {
           // while (guess != answer && guess != 0){ //If guess and 0 is not answer, continue.

          // if (guess > answer && guess != 0){ //If guess is higher than answer
              //  System.out.println ("You guessed too high!");
              //  guess = scan.nextInt();

          //  }
          //  else{
             //   if (guess < answer && guess != 0){ //If guess is lower than answer
              //      System.out.println ("You guessed too low!");
              //      guess = scan.nextInt();
              //  }

           //     else if (guess == answer){ //If guess equals answer
                 //   System.out.println ("You got it! Good guessing!");
         //       }
         //       else if (guess == 0){ //Game ends
                   // System.out.println ("You have ended your game. Goodbye.");
        //        }
        //            }
       //         }
     //   if (guess == answer){
          //  System.out.println ("You got it! Good guessing!");
     //   }

       // System.out.println ("Want to play again? (yes or no)?");
        //again = scan.next();
    //}
  //}
        }
}
```

Output:

```
I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. Guess what it is: (or enter 0 to quit) 50
You guessed too high!
40
You guessed too high!
30
You guessed too high!
20
You guessed too high!
10
You guessed too high!
1
You guessed too low!
5
You got it! Good guessing!
```

As you see from the comments in my code, I tried to duplicate the loop while also adding an if else statement and a question to ask the user if they want to play again. Is there an easier and working way to do re trigger the loop to make the game go on again?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you have to do:

```
boolean playAgain = true;
        while(playAgain){
            //your game code here
            System.out.println("Type yes to play again, No to exit");
            Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s = answer.next();//this will take the answer of the user
            answer.nextLine();//this will make sure it can take next input by returning new line
            if(s.trim().toLowerCase().equals("yes")){
                playAgain = true;//if the player wants to play again, the loop will repeat
            }else{
                playAgain = false;//else the loop will exit
            }
        }
```

Comment: I used your code and it sort of worked, however, when the loop started over it automatically said that I won instead of allowing me to insert more numbers.

Comment: @Learning_Java That means that you have to reset your important variables to their initial values _inside_ the `while(playAgain)` loop, i.e. right after `while(playAgain)` and before the game code.

Comment: Alright that makes sense, Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways, either add a while(true) loop to the entire program, and break if the user chooses to not play again, or use functions.

Edit: Functions would be overly complicated for a small program, just do this:

```
while(true){

//code here

   if(notReplay){ //notReplay is a boolean that is true when player does not want to play again
       break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to put your loop inside another loop. For example:

```
boolean playAgain = true;
while (playAgain) {
    //Insert your main while loop here
    //ask the user if he wants to play again after your main loop, and change playAgain variable accordingly..
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use this to completely rerun yout java program:

```
try{
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java YOURFILENAME");
    System.exit(0);
} catch (Exception exc){
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That's a bad solution even if it works.  It may not work, for a number of reasons.

Comment: @ajb please tell me why you think this is a bad solution

Comment: Because all he wants to do is go back to the beginning of the program.  This is best accomplished by simply jumping back (which you can do with a loop).  Your solution means going through the entire OS process of looking for the Java program, reloading it into memory, and whatever other setup is needed to start up Java again.  This is a huge waste compared to simply jumping back to another statement.